# Forked branch is updated while being 1 commit behind the master branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge

I am working on a forked repo.

I pushed a commit yesterday which was merged with the master branch a couple of hours later. I kept working on my fork without pulling in the new merged master, so my local files are technically "1 commit behind".

I usually `git pull upstream` to keep my local files up-to-date, but this time my local files are updated and I do not want to lose my changes because I will commit them right after the `git pull upstream`.

My question is: How do I merge my local repo with the master repo while keeping my changes so I can then commit and push the updates files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for:

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

This will update your repo and put your changes ahead.